# Scrapy Follow externals links

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I would like to crawl indefinitely the websites.
My scraper don't follow externals links.
How can i do this ?

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from dirbot.settings import *
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from urlparse import urlparse

class MyItem(Item):
    url= Field()

class someSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'infinit'
    allowed_domains = ['*']             
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com']

    rules = (Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_obj', follow=True),)

    def parse_obj(self,response):
        item = MyItem()
        item['url'] = []
        for link in LxmlLinkExtractor().extract_links(response):
            parsed_uri = urlparse(link.url)
            url = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=parsed_uri)
            insert_table(url)
```

Thank's

Comment: Marked as a duplicate - let me know if the linked topic does not solve the problem.

Comment: I don't understand how do this.<br /> The topic don't solve my problem :/

Comment: Don't specify `allowed_domains` at all and deactivate [`OffSiteMiddleware`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite) as anwers in the linked topic state.